# Admissible heuristics in a maze when the initial location is not known

Tags: algorithm, search, artificial-intelligence, graph-algorithm

This is part of homework assignment in [Berkeley AI course](https://edge.edx.org/courses/BerkeleyX/CS188x-8/Artificial_Intelligence/courseware/c78976d210314651abb740912d8279bb/d35abd173ee745dda5417aaa89b97b02/). As it is not active right now, I can't get help from the instructors and hence question to the community.

**Problem:**

It is night and you control a single insect. You know the maze, but you do not know what square the insect will start in. You must pose a search problem whose solution is an all-purpose sequence of actions such that, after executing those actions, the insect will be on the exit square, regardless of initial position. The insect executes the actions mindlessly and does not know whether its moves succeed: if it uses an action which would move it in a blocked direction, it will stay where it is.

Question is which of the following are admissible heuristics in a maze when initial position is not known:

A) Total number of possible locations the insect might be in.
B) The maximum of Manhattan distances to the goal from each possible location the insect could be in.
C) The minimum of Manhattan distances to the goal from each possible location the insect could be in.

It seems answers are both (B) and (C). Can't get my head around (B) being the right answer. It seems to me that (B) will be greater than actual cost of arriving at goal state  (if I am nearer to the goal which of-course is unknown at this point) and hence shouldn't be admissible.

Anybody can help me out withe reasoning of why maximum manhattan distance from each possible location is admissible heuristic in this case?

Comment: what section of the course is that?

Comment: Its the part of the homework hosted at http://ai.berkeley.edu/homework.html  I have given the link in the question itself and also updated the question with the original problem statement.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the insect can always make a single move directly to the goal state from anywhere in the maze, you can trivially show both A and B to be inadmissible.  Assuming it is possible for the insect to be 1 action away from the goal, any heuristic that evaluates to greater than 1 is inadmissible.  If any position requires 2 moves, B will evaluate to higher than 1 and is therefore inadmissible.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question, as the answers B and C are both admissible.